# Where can i programatically find where the log4j log files are stored?

Tags: java, log4j

Relative paths are used in the log4j.properties file.

How can i find the absolute path programatically where logs are stored?

Comment: But... why do you want to do that? Log4J is somehow supposed to abstract that from you.

Comment: @Pascal, Would like to provide log access via a visual interface for download.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From: http://www.gunith.com/2010/11/how-to-get-the-file-path-of-a-log4j-log-file/

Assume the log4j.properties file is as below,

```
log4j.logger.migrationlog = INFO, migration
log4j.appender.migration = org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.migration.File = C:/work/log/migration.log
log4j.appender.migration.MaxFileSize=20MB
log4j.appender.migration.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.migration.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.migration.layout.conversionPattern = %d %-5p %c - %m%n
```

In such case, your Java code should be as follows,

```
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("migrationlog"); //Defining the Logger
FileAppender appender = (FileAppender)logger.getAppender("migration");
return new File(appender.getFile());
```

Note that **migrationlog** was used to create the logger object in the first line.
And **migration** is used to get the FileAppender which in turn calls getFile() to get the log File object.

Comment: Just one mistake I did:
Consider to use `(FileAppender)logger.getRootLogger().getAppender("migration")` in case you work with the root Logger. Else you will get a NullPointerException.

Comment: can you tell how to create a file in the same path

Answer (score 3):

I think one way is like this:

since the path is relative to system property "user.dir"

so relative path = `./app.log`  becomes  `{user.dir}/app.log`

```
get user.dir as System.getproperty("user.dir").
```