# Get Log4j2 log file location to write to directory containing a date

Tags: java, junit, log4j, log4j2

How can I get the location of a log4j log file? I tried this: [Where can i programatically find where the log4j log files are stored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3217296/where-can-i-programatically-find-where-the-log4j-log-files-are-stored)

But it doesn't work for newer versions of log4j.

I am creating the file with the system date inside it, but when I retrieve the path, the time stamp would have changed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have configured an appender as follows:

```js
<File name="Technical" 
      fileName="app/${date:yyyy-MM-dd HHmmss}/logTechnical.log">
  <PatternLayout pattern="%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n" />
</File>
```

You can get the directory as follows:

```java
import java.io.File;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.FileAppender;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configuration;

...

LoggerContext ctx = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
Configuration config = ctx.getConfiguration();
FileAppender techical = (FileAppender) config.getAppender("Technical");
File dir = new File(techical.getFileName().replaceFirst("[^\\/]+$", ""));
```

Comment: Wow, I tried something like this, and it was saying I couldn't cast an Apender to a FileApender. Thanks so much, again Paul

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps somebody, my scenario was subtly different:
I had external code trying to get the older log4j FileAppender instance purely for the purposes of getting the file path.

As I was upgrading to log4j2 where the above was no longer viable, I instead updated my utility class to subtly amend [Paul Vargas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/870248/paul-vargas) answer and return the file location directly. In essences, just doing away with the construction of the File object instance:

```
    public static String getFileAppenderPath() {
        LoggerContext ctx = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(true);
        Configuration config = ctx.getConfiguration();
        FileAppender rollingFileAppender = (FileAppender) config.getAppender("RollingFileAppender");
        return rollingFileAppender.getFileName().replaceFirst("[^\\/]+$", "");
    }
```