# Log4j creating empty file before its needed

Tags: file, log4j, appender

I've got an application that runs every 15 minutes, 23 hours a day.  Most of the time, it 'wakes' up, sees there is no data to process and closes. During the initialization and input data check, there are DEBUG log statements that write to the console only.  Only once the application has found data to process does it write anything to a log file (INFO level and higher).  Problem is, the 'no data to process' runs are creating empty log files, even though nothing is ever written to them.  As this turns on almost 100 times a day, this behavior is undesirable.

I can easily implement a method to manually delete these files if they are unneeded, but this seems...hacky.  Is there a way to make Log4j wait on creating the log file until something is actually written to it?  Thanks!

Relevant portion of log4j.properties:

```
log4j.appender.myFileLogger=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.myFileLogger.Append=false
log4j.appender.myFileLogger.File=D:/Imaging/myApp/logs/myApp_${current.date}.log
log4j.appender.myFileLogger.threshold=INFO
log4j.appender.myFileLogger.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.myFileLogger.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Comment: You could remove the HH:mm:ss portion from your filename and have a daily log? I think there might be value in knowing that nothing was processed, and perhaps logging that explicitly.  Alas, I'm sorry I don't actually have an answer to your question.  It is interesting.

Comment: Rolling daily logs were the original solution, and I may very well fall back to that.  Its a strange setup as the input data is delivered whenever is convenient, so several input files may be delivered at once and processed sequentially.  The hope was to get a single log file for each processing run/input file, but its a minor issue in either direction.  Mostly curiosity at this point :)

Answer (score 1):

There is an option in File appender called "createOnDemand" which could be of use:

*createOnDemand boolean The appender creates the file on-demand. The appender only creates the file when a log event passes all filters and is routed to this appender. Defaults to false.*

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else ever comes across this, here's how I 'solved' this:

```
if(deleteLog) {
    FileAppender appender = (FileAppender)Logger.getRootLogger().getAppender("myFileLogger");
    String path = appender.getFile();
    Logger.shutdown();
    Files.delete(Paths.get(path));
}
```

This still feels a bit hackish, but it works without needing extra config points or hard coded file paths.  Make sure to call logger.shutdown() or else Log4j will still have an open handle on the file, throwing a "another process is using this file" error.

Basil Musa's answer provided the basis for this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9480213/5780475